# How can I open the Visual Studio EditorConfig Designer after changing the default editor for the .editorconfig file type?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig, visual-studio-designer

**Does anyone know how to either add back in the EditorConfig Designer as a program to open files with or how to reset the default editors for file types?**

After changing the default editor for .editorconfig files to be something other than the EditorConfig Designer the option to set the default editor back to the designer or to open with the designer is now gone.

I know I can probably delete my appdata folder or something like that and reset it that way, I'm looking for a way to do it that doesn't take doing that. I did a quick search in some of the xml files visual studio uses but realized it would take some time to figure out exactly what to do to add it back in myself, thus I'm asking with hopes someone has experience doing this.

One work around I have found is to set the files to open with a text editor with text encoding then hit cancel when it asks which encoding to use. It then opens the designer but it still won't show up as an option to set as the default or in the open with items, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no way to manually add the EditorConfig Designer back into the list editors. You can still use the designer by following these steps:

> 1. set the files to open with "text editor with text encoding"
> 2. double click on a .editorconfig file to open it
> 3. hit cancel when it asks which encoding to use
> 4. the EditorConfig Designer will open for the selected file.

Comment: "set the files to open with "text editor with text encoding"" it is entirely unclear what you mean by this, or how to achieve this.  Also, there is no such thing as "text editor with text encoding". There is "Source Code (Text) Editor With Encoding", did you mean that?

Comment: Didn't think it was unclear, setting a file to open with a certain type of editor is the same parlance one would use regarding setting a file in windows to open with a default program. You are setting that type of file to open with a particular editor type by default, ie it will automatically use that editor type when you double-click on the file.

Comment: Also no I didn't mean that, I meant any text editor with encoding as an option... source code, HTML,  XML all have that option and they are all text editors. Doesn't matter which one you use, all that matters is you hit cancel when it asks what type of encoding to use.

Comment: Point 1 means: select .editoconfig, right-click, select Source Code (Text) Editor With Encoding

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same situation and ended up deleting the `.vs` folder. I didn't have any other personalized config in there.